# downloading thru ajax and iframe?

Tags: jquery

I have this small piece if code:

```
$.post('exportToExcel.php', function(data) {

    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.src = ""+data;
    iframe.style.display = "none";

    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
});
```

But nothing happens, I'm trying to download a file seamless from the server thru jquery's ajax.

Anyone got a good fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are simply trying to direct the user to a file, download you should use a regular link or use `location.href = 'my_url';` to send the browser there directly.

Alternatively, if you really want to do it this 'seamless' way, don't use an AJAX POST.  Just link directly to `exportToExcel.php` in the `iframe`.

If `exportToExcel.php` *requires* the use of POST, make the `iframe` visible and when `exportToExcel.php` is called via `GET`, provide a 'Download' button which is the same size as the `iframe` and, when clicked, submits a regular HTML form to the same URL via POST.

Comment: would your last suggestion differ so much from my code above?

Comment: The difference in my third example is that it uses an `iframe` and just regular HTTP.  No JS or AJAX required. You could, however, put some JS into the frame page that automatically clicks the button or submits the POST form.